# How to shade the area under a line with discrete value

Tags: matlab

I am dealing with data from wells, sometimes the tool does not pick up any signal, and that interval will be blank = NaN. 
I want to shade under the area of this line but not in the section with no data.

for example: 
x=[1 2 3 NaN NaN 6 7]
y=[5 6 6.5 NaN NaN 6 8]

Removing the NaN from the data is not desired. I tried using fill and area, but doesnt work
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an intrinsic MATLAB function for doing an area plot with NaN but you could iterate over each section of "good" values and plot them separately like this:

```
function testShade()

x=[1 2 3 NaN NaN 6 7]
y=[5 6 6.5 NaN NaN 6 8]

figure(89);
clf;
plot(x,y, '-rx', 'linewidth', 3);
hold on;
areaWithNaN(x,y);

function areaWithNaN(x,y)

badValues = isnan(x);

while(~isempty(badValues))

    ind = find(badValues, 1, 'last');

    % if we didn't find anything then plot everything that remains:
    if isempty(ind)
        ind = 0;
    end

    % If there are multiple bad values in a row then trim them off. This
    % could be slow and optimized later:
    if ind == length(badValues)
        badValues= badValues(1:end-1);
        continue;
    end

    area(x(ind+1:length(badValues)), y(ind+1:length(badValues)));

    % remove the bad values we no longer care about:
    badValues= badValues(1:ind-1);

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Any interpolation functions will fill in the missing dots.
Example:
Given the data set:

```
x=1:5;
y=[11 12 NaN 15 30 NaN];
```

Create a data set without Nan;

```
x1=x;
y1=y;
x1(isnan(y))=[];
y1(isnan(x))=[];
```

use interpolation

```
yNew=interp1(x1,y1,x);
```

This is the simplest interpolation, user types may be found in the help section of [interp1](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) function